# 100% width of col-xs-12 in mobile view using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have box in my HTML page. The box width responsive. on desktop it should take `540px` width and in mobile the box should take `100%` width. the is centre align in desktop. The problem I am facing is that on mobile view the box width is not touching the device width because of container class. This problem can be fixed for using `.row` class but when I use class it is also expending the width of box on desktop. Can this require be achieved without writing extra media query. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MDaYp/embedded/result/)

```
<div class="container">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 box">
<div class="col-md-12" style="background:#022243">
content....
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you modify the CSS for the col-xs-12 class ? Or just add another class to the div and define that in the media queries you need it to be active.

Comment: I suppose you could add to the col-xs-12 class something that breaks its parent container? Not ideal, but only way i can think of without using media queries

Comment: I mean to done it with bootstrap media queries only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using media queries is the fastest and most reliable way to attain what you need here I think but If you do not want to then for me my approach is this..

```
<div class="container hidden-xs visible-sm-block">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 box">
     <div class="col-md-12" style="background:#022243">
       content....
     </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="row visible-xs-block hidden-sm">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 box">
     <div class="col-md-12" style="background:#022243">
       content....
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Not tried yet but I think this will satisfy your problem.

Hope it helps

Comment: This probably is the best answer to his question to be honest, but obviously requires duplicating content.

Comment: @joegandy Yes, you just mention one of the boootstrap weakness.. populating the DOM with so much `element` e.g. `div` :=)

Answer (score 1):

See js fiddle:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jutyp/)

Did a new mobile class to remove padding on mobile from container, also added padding:0; on col-xs-12

```
.col-xs-12 {
    padding:0;
}
@media (max-width : 480px) {
    .mobile_fix {
        padding:0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I mention above, without writing extra @media queries

Comment: Yep I apologize I must've miss read it on first scan I can't imagine being able to do this with out media queries without using some kind of js hack? (Different sizes for different size screens = media queries). Sorry for the miss reading of the original post

Comment: I mean to do it with bootstrap media queries only

Comment: You can just add the .container { padding : 0; } into the (max-width : 480px;) query in the bootstrap css file